# Does an HttpWebRequest work with https?

Tags: .net, vb.net, https, httpwebrequest

I have a program that just gets the html from a service with the httpwebrequest object in VB.NET. It works when the service is an http// but does not work when it is an https//. I am using the GET method (just reading the page with a streamreader for its html code).

Is there some additional code needed to make this work? Is it even possible?

If anyone has some sample code for an https web request in VB.NET (or JAVA) it would really help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **yes, it does work**. You can read about it in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) (and get sample code too).

If you need to know why in your specific scenario it doesn't you'll have to update your question with sample code that fails and most importantly details about the thrown exception, if any.